# Linux command line regex

Tags: regex, macos, bash, shell

I would like to search into directory for all files end by .m for string like @"LBL_18989"  @"LBL_15459" , @"LBL_14359" ...

My command is :

```
find . type f -name \*.m | grep '@"LBL_[[0-9]"]+'
```

but it does not give the expected result.

Comment: @F.J. - editing the post to correct an error with his code causes confusion.

Comment: The original find command was: `find . type f -name *.m | grep '@"LBL_[[0-9]"]+'`. It won't allow me to change the post because removing a "\" is not a 6 character change.

Comment: Are you trying to grep for files names with that string pattern or files containing text data with that pattern?

Comment: @jordanm, I didn't edit anything except to add indentation for the code formatting to make it easier to read.  I think the OP actually intended to have the `\*` there (since there is no need to escape a `*` to get it to show up in SO).

Comment: F.J. - sorry, I didn't look at the source differences, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always quote your arguments. Your -name pattern for find contains an "*", which means the shell will try to expand it as a glob before passing it to find. You can also use -regex instead of piping the output of find to grep.

```
find . -type f -regex '@"LBL_[[:digit:]"]+'
```

Based on jdi's comment, you may be wanted to search the contents of those files for the given regex. If so, you can use the following:

```
find . type f -name '*.m' -exec grep -E '@"LBL_[[:digit:]"]+' /dev/null {} +
```

Comment: I was actually just typing that edit as an answer myself. You can also write it as: `-exec grep -H -E '@"LBL_[[:digit:]"]+' {} \;`

Comment: @jdi - Yes, which is the way I would normally use but `-H` is not POSIX and the question is tagged OSX.

Comment: I am on an OSX box right now. Works just fine for me regardless

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs for me. However, the regular expression you stated in the question will match a lot more than just the filenames in your example list. This can be a problem if you are looking to see if your filenames need name validation because some will validate that really shouldn't. Your regex pattern

grep '@"LBL_[[0-9]"]+'

also matches filenames such as

1. @"LBL_"
2. @"LBL_2"
3. @"LBL_3"3"
4. @"LBL_"4

If your list is really representative I would instead use

grep '@"LBL_[[0-9]]+"'

and move the quote character to after the plus, at the end of the pattern.
You can use grep and maybe that's your use case, but if you use egrep or grep with the -E switch you get to use the [[:digit:]] class. POSIX.2 frowns on ranges in a bracket expression using the dash character. From the POSIX specification: "Ranges are very collating-sequence-dependent, and portable programs should avoid relying on them."