# Bash script reg-exp and objective-c

Tags: objective-c, regex, bash

I am a new in scripting language and I would like help for you guys

I would like to create a file named constant.h and search into all files *.m in specific directory for a reg-exp `@"LBL_[[0-9]]+"` ex: @"LBL_75847", and write those matchs to constant.h if there are not written (no duplication into the file constants) like this

```
NSString *const C_LBL_[[0-9]] = thematch; // exp NSString *const C_LBL_78787 = @"LBL_78787";
```

moreover this script should also replace all matched @"LBL_[[0-9]]+" into *.m files with the constant var which is  C_LBL_[[0-9]]+

Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the exact same question yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105541/linux-command-line-regex

Comment: no actually I want a complete script that found the match and save it into a file like this NSString *CLBL_26000 = @"LBL_26000";

Comment: I have objective c classes which contain a lot of strings around 2000 like @"LBL_134343" and actually I want to export all this string in one file constant.h ex: NSString *CLBL_26000 = @"LBL_26000" and replace all string in the classes with the constant/var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
$ cat ocstr.awk

# If the code contains @"LBL_....", replace it with C_LBL_... and
# remember the labels for later.
match($0, /@"LBL_[0-9]*\"/) {
        S=$0; P=""

        do        # Loop until there's nothing left in the right half
        {
                A[L=substr(S, RSTART+2, RLENGTH-3)]++; # Remember label
                P=P substr(S, 1, RSTART-1) "C_" L;
                S=substr(S, RSTART+RLENGTH);
        }
        while(match(S, /@"LBL_[0-9]*\"/)); # Keep hunting for more labels

        $0=P S; # Update the line to be printed
}

# If we are given file.pm, print into file.m
{       O=FILENAME;
        sub(/[.]pm$/, ".m", O);
        print > O;      }

END {
        for(L in A) printf("NSString *const C_%s = @\"%s\";\n", L, L);
}

$ awk -f ocstr.awk dir/*.pm > list

$ cat list

NSString *const C_LBL_10011 = @"LBL_10011";
NSString *const C_LBL_10012 = @"LBL_10012";
NSString *const C_LBL_10804 = @"LBL_10804";
NSString *const C_LBL_10000 = @"LBL_10000";

$ cat dir/*.m

tableviewlogin.backgroundView = nil;
    [welcometitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONTB size:FONTSIZETITLE]];
    [welcometitle setText:[MSharedFunctions UF8ErrorMessageForCode:C_LBL_10000]];
    [welcometitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    NSString *buttontitle = [MSharedFunctions UF8ErrorMessageForCode:C_LBL_10012];
    [forgotpassword setTitle:buttontitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [forgotpassword setTitle:buttontitle forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:[MSharedFunctions UF8ErrorMessageForCode:C_LBL_10011]];
    [[self tabBarItem] setTitle:[MSharedFunctions UF8ErrorMessageForCode:C_LBL_10804]];

$
```